# Typescript property does not exist in a union

Tags: typescript

I have the following types:

```
Foo {
 foobar: any
}

Bar {
 fooBarBar: any;
}
```

A function defined as such:

```
this.api.submit(param: Foo | Bar)
```

usage:

```
this.api.submit(param.foobar) // does not exist on Bar

Error: Property 'foobar' does not exist on type 'Foo| Bar'.
  Property 'foobar' does not exist on type 'Bar '
```

My assumption was typescript would figure based on the union it could be either of these models, so why does it complain in this instance?

A workaround is to use the bracket notation param['foobar'] and the error will disappear...

Comment: You can cast a variable to specific type: `(param as Foo).foobar`

Comment: But, then why are you allow type Bar, if it has no property  foobar, and you want to use the property foobar in anycase ?

Comment: the bracket notation is basically "swimming against typescript", by bypassing any check. It defeats the whole point of having the "protection" of using a typed language on top of JS.

Comment: yeah i know - just stating one could always revert to the js type hacks :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your definition says is that `param` will be **either** `Foo` or `Bar`, but there's no way for the compiler to decide which at the point you call `param.foobar`.

If you want to be able to discriminate, you can do something like this:

```
Foo {
    type: 'foo',
    foobar: any
}

Bar {
    type: 'bar',
    fooBarBar: any;
}
...
if (param.type === 'foo') {
    param.foobar; // the type guard in the if statement guarantees we've got an instance of Foo here
}
```

If what you wanted to say is that `param` will be **both** `Foo` and `Bar`, you need [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types), i.e.: `Foo & Bar`.

Comment: nice use of guards, can't you use the "builtin" typeguard, though ? something like `param is Bar`

Comment: literally just picked up on the intersection type, thanks +1

Comment: @Pac0 Not directly, you can however do `if ((param as Foo).foobar) { ... }` but it looks a bit ugly. You can also define typeguard functions, e.g. `function isFoo(p):p is Foo {return (p as Foo).foobar;}`, and then say `if (isFoo(param)) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

It's working as intended.

If it can be either a type with property `foobar` or a type **without**, then your are not guaranteed that the property exist.

So you might run into trouble if you assume it exists on every valid reference.

So, TypeScript complains.

Maybe you can indicate that `Bar` may have a (potentially undefined) `foobar` property :

```js
Foo {
 foobar: any
}

Bar {
 foobar?: any;
 fooBarBar: any;
}
```

You should be using only properties that you know are there on all of the union type.

Basically, you can see the union type as an interface that comprise the all the **common** properties.