# Typescript array with types of object or string cannot access object key values

Tags: typescript, types

I'm new to typescript. I have this very confusing issue where in i can't access what's inside the object since it's type is object or string. The output error is :

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'string | test'.
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Is there any way to infer the specific array data to my interface test without redeclaring it to another variable?

My code is :

```
interface test {
 id:number;
 details:string;
} 
let z : Array<string|test> = ['hello',{ 
 id:4,
 details:'heyheyhey'
}]

 console.log(z[1].id)
```

Comment: Because technically `z[1]` could be a string, and a string will not have the `id` property. Is `z` always constant? Then you can use `let z: [string, test]` but I suspect that is not your usecase.

Comment: There has to be a canonical question for this, but I can't find it. ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58978429/typescript-property-does-not-exist-in-a-union) is close.) Basically, you need to *narrow* the type with a type guard, since strings don't have an `id` property: `if ("id" in z[1]) { console.log(z[1].id); }` Or `if (typeof z[1] === "object")` would work as well because the other type in your union is a string.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is correct. If you perform type-narrowing before hand, then TypeScript will be okay with it, because then it "knows" `z[1]` is definitely not `string`, and therefore can only be `test`, e.g. `console.log(typeof z[1] !== 'string' && z[1].id)`

Comment: I found this hard since i have encountered this issue with the library React Query where in the first parameter of the query is an array that contains key of string as index 0 and any as the second parameter. i used object since it was a lot cleaner but when i try to access it using array[1]. It threw some error. Do you have any idea how to implement the said fix to my code base on the details provided. I'm new at typescript and is still trying to improve